# Creating an android app that doesn't show in the installed list for rooted OS?

Tags: android, rooted-device

I am an experienced android developer who doesn't have a lot of experience exploiting the capabilities of a rooted android OS. I wanted to create an android application for my rooted phone which doesn't show up in the running services,installed apps,system apps list..etc..

How can this be done?Can someone orient me in the right direction?

Thanks and Regards,

Roger

Comment: perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803706/how-to-hide-application-from-showing-in-menu) will be helpful.

Comment: Not what i am looking for exactly

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. you can only hide your application from menu launcher but application is showed on the installed app and running services.

There is only one solution to achieve what you want : Build your own firmware