# I want to popup if user come in gps range using android development?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, android-launcher

**I have a question related to the gps system in android.**

I want to have the following functionality in my android app:

-Once the application is installed on the android device then it is always running in the background.

-I have a gps enabled android device then if I am 300-400 meters away from a particular address(Where address means we have provided the address to the application for finding location) then a popup appears on the screen stating I am x meters away from the target. (I would want this popup to occur every time I am 100m closer)

I have tried looking on Google for the correct way to do this but I have been unsuccessful and any help would be appreciated.

My main problems are:

1)Always having my program running in the background.

2)Have a popup to notify the user.

3)How to calculate my distance from a particular location.

Comment: Hey Hemant. I have edited your post to try to make it more obvious what you are asking.

Comment: thanks @TheOneWhoPrograms for editing my question.
Please give me solution about question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer, but I saw a good opportunity to edit your question to make it more attractive for others to answer it with higher quality answers. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations) in meter by

```
Location location;
float distance[];
location.distanceBetween(From Latitude, From Longitude, TO Latitude, TO Longitude,
                        distance);
```

When you user goes 300 meter , you can popup the screen in home activity (Use background service to do that)

Once app installed stat the service. Remember that user can [kill the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803706/how-to-hide-application-from-showing-in-menu?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: where i put the distance 300 meter in the program.
and how can i start the service for particular my app. means what code i wright for that. @AnanThDev

Comment: Please anyone give me some coding example about how i create service in background about above query. Please give me solution i really appreciate that person who helping me.

Comment: Link 1:- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Link 2:-http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FGPSLogger

Comment: first link you provided i already applied but not getting success because my problem is different. 
Second link you provided if i run the project then in the logcat it shows like that:-    
Service Started with interval 5, Logfile name: GPSLog.2014-04-04 05:03:37.kml.
But what does this application do i don't understand, and also nothing file is shown in the DDMS under /sdcard. please help me for this issue.